# Record number of clicks into database

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, flask, record

I want to record the number of clicks an image has into my database so that I can use that information and view it in a different html page. I already have the counter done but I don't know how to put it into my database. Our professor instructed us to use python flask and javascript and postgresql. So I've tried this method but I'm getting an error 500.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food"/><img src="food/eggs.jpg" style="width:100%" id="eggs_img" onclick="document.getElementById('egg_play').play(); insert('eggs'); return false;" alt="Eggs">
```

javascript:

```
function egg_clicks() {
var egg = 0;
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/food_rec',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'egg': $("#egg").val()
            }),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (e) {
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.status == 'ok') {
                    egg++;
                    alert("Successfully updated!")

                 }
                else {
                    alert("ERROR")
                }

            }
        });
}
```

app.py:

```
app.route('/food_rec', methods=['POST'])
def egg_clicks():

params = request.get_json()
egg = params["egg"]

res = spcall("egg_clicks", egg, True)

if 'Error' in res[0][0]:
    return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': res[0][0]})
return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'message': res[0][0]})
```

stored procedure:

```
    create or replace function egg_clicks( in egg int) returns int as
   $$
     declare
     loc_res text;

     loc_egg int;
      begin
      select into loc_egg egg from food where food_name = 'eggs';
      if egg NOTNULL then

       insert into food (clicks) values (egg);
       loc_res = 'ok';

      else
       loc_res = 'Error';
       end if;
       return loc_res;
      end;
    $$
    language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: `javascript` - shouldn't you be sending something to the server? `egg = params["egg"]` - the server seems to be waiting for it

Comment: i used an onclick button on the html so that when it's clicked, the counter is incremented and the value on the counter should be the one recorded in the database

Comment: web pages don't work like that - `var egg` in a web page isn't magically transformed into an AJAX request with a parameter called `egg` and sent to the server just because your server has a parameter called `egg` in a request handler that has no relevance to the html page that has the var egg - you need to write that code - suggest you invesitage the term AJAX

Comment: seems like a bad approach what if two people open your page at the same time. the first clicks it 10 times, then the second click ir once.